# Code blocks wxWidgets no such file or directory

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, wxwidgets, codeblocks

I have problem when I try to compile my project in Code Blocks with wxWidgets, I was looking everywhere solution for my problem but nothing was good for me and nowhere was explained how to solve this problem...

I post image of my problem here http://postimage.org/image/ngejv16d3/

Comment: Perhaps your searches would go better if you could spell properly... Copy and paste are your friends.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with greatwolf. Or you can use DOS path instead (in command prompt go to C:\ and execute `dir /x`, it will display the DOS version of `Program Files (x86)` folder (without spaces). Then you can change your wx path accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The fully qualified path of your wxWidget location is getting truncated, most likely due to spaces in the path. Two possible ways to fix it, you can move your wxWidget install to another directory with the *spaces removed* or you can try enclosing your current path in `""` double quotes when it gets passed to the compiler.